# How to set a nested datasource from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, repeater, sqldatasource

Connection String (Conn) is set globally on page load.

*(As below. I use this for all sqldatasources and it work perfectly.)*

**VB.NET (Page Load)**

```
Imports Connections
Dim Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(StringConn).ConnectionString
  sqlRepeater.ConnectionString = Conn.ConnectionString
End Sub
```

---

### How to set a nested datasource from code behind?

I have a nested gridview inside a repeater and am trying to set the sqldatasource's connectionstring on itemdatabound instead of page load. *(As below.)*

**VB.NET (Repeater Item Databound)**

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpt.ItemDataBound
  If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    Dim sqlGridview As SqlDataSource = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("sqlGridview"), SqlDataSource)
    sqlGridview.ConnectionString = Conn.ConnectionString
  End If
End Sub
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="Server" DataSourceID="sqlRepeater">
  <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sqlGridview">
      ...
    </GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGridview" runat="Server" SelectCommand="sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"/>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlRepeater" runat="Server" SelectCommand="sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"/>
```

---

This code outputs error:

**The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.**

---

### TRIED TO CREATE FUNCTION TO PASS IN THE CONNECTION STRING

**ASPX**

Replaceed above sqlsource with this to call function

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGridview" runat="Server" SelectCommand="sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" ConnectionString='<%# GetConnectionString()%>'/>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Protected Function GetConnectionString() As String
  Dim Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(StringConn).ConnectionString
  Return Conn.ConnectionString
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an idea, but the problem might be the fact that by the time `ItemDataBound` is called GridView's data binding is already done, or was attempted to be done. And during this attempt a connection string was not set indeed.

To correct that you might want to do two things. First - set connection string in markup, so that data source has it before data binding is done. Something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGridview" runat="Server"
                   ConnectionString='<%# GetConnectionString(); %>' ... />
```

Where `GetConnectionString` is a protected method in code behind that just returns the 
connection string:

```
Protected Function GetConnectionString() As String
    Return Conn.ConnectionString
End Function
```

Of course that means that there is no need to handle `ItemDataBound` anymore, unless you were doing something else there as well.

Second - reverse the order of controls inside the item template. This most likely is not necessary, but I am not entirely sure about an exact time when the GridView will be data bound, so this will help to ascertain that connection string is set:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGridview" runat="Server"
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="Server" ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You are on the money. I neglected to mention in my answer above that when connectionString is applied on the page markup all works well. The issue is I need to use code behind due to additional connection variables I am using. Additional moving the source had no effect.

Comment: @Obsidion, unless your additional logic is control/item specific, the suggested solution should suffice for your needs. Cause it is still code behind.

Comment: @Obsidion, actually it should do even if you have some item specific logic for connection, since you can easily pass whatever you want as a parameter of `GetConnectionString`

Comment: By protected method do you mean create a funtion containing the connection logic?

Comment: @Obsidion, yep. Updated the answer with an example. `protected` is used because `private` is not visible on markup, and there is no reason for `public`

Comment: @Obsidion, quite hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Brilliant @Andrei ! I just ran into the same problem, and never thought to change the previously hard-coded connection string to a reference to a Code-Behind method, but it makes perfect sense! Now I can dynamically set my database on a whim in the code-behind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Your Class Library

Use this to cast initially the sqlConnection then execute the connection when using it.

Public Class MyLibrary

```
'-------------------SQL Database Variables----------------
Dim SerialMACDatabase As String = Nothing
Dim SerialMac As SqlConnection
Dim CMD As New SqlCommand
Dim sqlAdapter As SqlDataAdapter

Public Sub New(ByVal lserialMACDatabase As String)
    SerialMACDatabase = lserialMACDatabase
End Sub

Private Sub connectToDB()
    Try
        SerialMac = New SqlConnection(SerialMACDatabase)
        SerialMac.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub 


Public Sub issueCommand(ByVal sQuery As String)
    Try
        connectToDB()
        CMD = New SqlCommand(sQuery, TestResult)
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
Dim Libraryy As New MyLibrary(strSQLCONNECTION)
```

Libraryy.IssueCommand("INSERT SOMETHING")

```
End Sub
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me? I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: Why ? if the The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. that means that sqlconnection is not yet initialize in your global variable.

Comment: I appreciate your help however the global connection string is initialised and working as it loads the repeater on page load with no issue. The problem is the gridview is not reading the connection information due to being nested in the repeater.